# Which utility class can be used to store and apply sort in Java

Tags: java, file, list, collections, text-files

I'm a bit confused that which of the utility classes can be used for this type of problem:
I have a file Movies.txt containing info like: `Id`, `Name`, `Director`, `Rating`. Rating may or may not be present.

Sample:

```
1,ABC,Mr. xyz,4.5
3,GHI,Mr. mno
2,DEF,Ms. stu,3
```

I need to read and store this file to the memory and then apply sort by `rating` as well as by `name` and then write to the file later on.
Which utility class can best help me in this situation, so that it can be an ease to do this if possible. No more files to be used.

Comment: `Collections` and `Arrays` can both do this, but you'll need to create POJO representation of your data first

Comment: i need to do this in Core Java. POJO i guess is used in Java Advanced. isn't it?

Comment: Have you read about / understood the differences between the various types of collections, arrays, sets, maps, etc that could be used? What have you tried so far?

Comment: POJO = plain old java object.

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal Pojo in the sense, A small light weight Object ,which holds related data of specific type.

Comment: i was trying to use ArrayList but it was more hectic to do with this. that is the reason why i call for your help.

Comment: Movies class implementing java.util.Comparator;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by defining a `Object` that describes the basic properties of a "Movie".  Take make your life easier, it might be a good idea to `implement Comparable<Movie>` directly.

```
public class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String directory;
    private double rating;

    public Movie(int id, String name, String directory, double rating) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.directory = directory;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDirectory() {
        return directory;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Movie o) {
        int diff = (int) asInt(getRating()) - asInt(o.getRating());
        if (diff == 0) {
            diff = getName().compareTo(name);
        }
        return diff;
    }

    protected int asInt(double value) {
        String text = Double.toString(value);
        text = text.replaceAll("\\.", "");
        return Integer.parseInt(text);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getId() + ", " + getName() + ", " + getDirectory() + ", " + getRating();
    }

}
```

Create a `List` to hold the incoming movies

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>(25);
```

Read the contents of the and parse each line into their separate property elements (I'll leave that you), add each newly create `Movie` to the list...

```
movies.add(new Movie(...));
```

Use `Collections.sort(movies)` to sort them...

For example...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SortExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>(5);
        movies.add(new Movie(1, "ABC", "Mr. xyz", 4.5));
        movies.add(new Movie(2, "GHI", "Mr. mno", 0));
        movies.add(new Movie(3, "DEF", "Ms. stu", 3));
        movies.add(new Movie(4, "AT1", "Mr. T", 3));

        System.out.println("Before....");
        for (Movie movie : movies) {
            System.out.println(movie);
        }

        Collections.sort(movies);

        System.out.println("After....");
        for (Movie movie : movies) {
            System.out.println(movie);
        }

    }

    public static class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> {

        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String directory;
        private double rating;

        public Movie(int id, String name, String directory, double rating) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.directory = directory;
            this.rating = rating;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getDirectory() {
            return directory;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public double getRating() {
            return rating;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Movie o) {
            int diff = (int) asInt(getRating()) - asInt(o.getRating());
            if (diff == 0) {
                diff = getName().compareTo(name);
            }
            return diff;
        }

        protected int asInt(double value) {
            String text = Double.toString(value);
            text = text.replaceAll("\\.", "");
            return Integer.parseInt(text);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getId() + ", " + getName() + ", " + getDirectory() + ", " + getRating();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @Jason don't worry! this is just an example not my homework. i need to learn this before implementing or copying.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read this input file one line at a time, parse each line by splitting at ',', constructing a Movie object (that you define) and adding to some kind of array / map / set. Then sort your array / map / set according to the instructions, and write out the response file.

Do some research into:

- reading lines from files
- parsing strings using split
- lists, maps
- sorting (compare)

Comment: i have done the first two points but got struck with the third point. Just help me in that point, that which class would be best for this situation and then i'll research on it.

Comment: See the comment from @upog above. And since you mentioned it before, take another look at ArrayList.

Comment: I would create a Movie class with the following attributes: id, name, director, rating. Make the class implement Comparable. Then put your Movie objects in the list and sort them using a method from Collections.

Answer (score 1):

OK, an answer has been accepted, but I have the right not to have the same opinion.

Comparable should reflect the relationship between 2 objects based on their entire state(of course, ids and other irrelevant fields are skipped). If you want to order some objects by their partial state(a few fields) you should use a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: i got point. after that answer i had gone through some research on them. but still, thanks for your answer. :)